# Drawing multiple images on canvas. but toDataURL returns blank

Tags: javascript, canvas

ok i am trying to draw multiple image blobs on canvas and thn once all done get one singleimage from canvas.basically i am trying to make a spritesheet.

```
for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  img = new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, column*width, row*height, width, height);
    column=column+1;
    if(column==11)
    {
      row=row+1;
      column=0;
    }
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(array[i]);
}

var DataURL=canvas.toDataURL();
```

but issue is i get transparent png. but if i append canvas to document correct image is there on canvas. i suspect something async here is ruing it. but cant figure it out.

Comment: canvas.toBlob(saveFrame, 'image/jpeg');  function saveFrame(blob) {
      array.push(blob);
    }. that is my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yes, you're right in your guess. You are trying to get the image from canvas right after your loop, but at this moment no images are acually loaded. So your action is to wait for all images to load, and only then try to save the canvas. It could be achieved through promises for example:

```
var promises = [];
for(...your loop) {
  ...
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.onload=function(){
        ...draw image...
        resolve(...resolve with your context...);
    }
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  });
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(array[i]);
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(...array of your contexts...) {
   ...make export here...
});
```

Second thing, is that the ability to get DataUrl depends from the sources of the images. If they are on the sepparate not your's domain, and they don't have cross-origin header with the * or your domains value, you will not be able to get the data, because the canvas becomes tainted according to Content Security Policy ([Explaining what is tainted canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)). But anyway, if this scenario will happen, the Chrome and other modern browsers should warn about it in console.